# I am trying to use react-three-fiber but it shows errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I am trying to use react-three-fiber but everytime i try to render it; react throws this error:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of `App`.

This is the "App" component.

```js
import './App.css';
import Header from "./Header";
import Body from "./Body";
import WebFont from "webfontloader";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Canvas } from "react-three-fiber";
import { sphereBufferGeometry, meshStandardMaterial } from 'three';


function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    WebFont.load({
      google: {
        families: ["Cookie", "Lora", "Playfair Display", "Inknut Antiqua", "Cormorant"]
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Canvas>
        <mesh>
          <sphereBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[1, 1, 1]} />
          <meshStandardMaterial attach="material" />
        </mesh>
      </Canvas>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: react-three-fiber has been deprecated, please use @react-three/fiber from now on

Comment: thank you, that seemed to be the problem